# Jquery - Load image repeating in IE7

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a very basic image load function in Jquery, this is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var img = new Image();  
    //  
    $(img).load(function () {  
        alert('loaded');  
    }).error(function () {  
        alert('error');  
    }).attr('src', 'images/loader.gif');  
});
```

In firefox it works fine but in IE7 it just keeps alerting 'loaded' over and over again, if I change the URL so its a broken link it outputs 'error' just once.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

My guess: Assigning a `src` value triggers a `load` event in IE7, hence the 'infinite' loop.
If image file does not exist, the load does not complete hence stops there and then.

Comment: how does this explain the infinite loop?

Comment: what o.k.w means probably is : 
load() -> attr() -> load() -> attr() ... this is infinite, assigning src triggers load which assigns again ...

Comment: I always figured that this was the usual way of doing image loads - I'm using the code from this page btw: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

Comment: '$(img).load(function ()' = OnImageLoad. `.attr('src', 'images/loader.gif')' assigns a source to the `<img>` resulting in another ImageLoad event, which then assign the source again and.... well endless recursive...

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197055%28VS.85%29.aspx.  Setting the src causes IE to load the image again, triggering the load event.

Comment: Ok I've looked at BStruthers link but not sure how I would work that code into my setup, I just want to preload an image then run a block of code once its loaded. This has a slightly different way of doing it but again the code runs on an infinate loop in IE7: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/preload-images-with-jquery.html - can anyone help me out?